# Exclude specific product variation from tax class filter hook in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax, product-variations

I am trying to apply a specific tax class by role in a wordpress filter. This tax class applies to variation products as well as regular single products. I just need to exclude a specific variation product or production variation by id.
Here is what I have so far:

```
 function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! empty( $user ) && in_array( 'MEMBER', $user->roles ) &&  is_product() && get_the_id() != 1337)   {
    $tax_class = 'Reduced rate';
  }
  return $tax_class;
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
```

I think im failing at the following part:
`is_product() && get_the_id() != 1337)`
as the tax class of 'Reduced rate' is applied to all products including the one im trying to exclude.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is `get_the_id()` that **can't work for product variations** on single **variable product** pages as it gives the variable product Id but not any product variation id...

Instead as you can see in your code, the hooked function has 2 available arguments, so you can use the variable `$product` to get the Id from it using the method `get_id()` as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'change_tax_class_user_role', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'change_tax_class_user_role', 10, 2 );
function change_tax_class_user_role( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $excluded_variation_id = 1337;
    $targeted_user_role    = 'MEMBER';

    if ( $product->is_type('variation') && $product->get_id() == $excluded_variation_id ) {
        return $tax_class;
    } 
    elseif ( current_user_can( $targeted_user_role ) ) {
        return 'Reduced rate';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec, but I am afraid it doesn't work as intended. The Reduced rate only gets applied if i leave the ` && is_product() && $product->get_id() != $excluded_variation_id` part out. All the selected Products should have the reduced rate, only the product with the id 1337 should have the standard rate.

The tax for the member role is 7% for everything apart from the Product im trying to target with the variation id 1337 which has 16% tax.

Do I have to fix that with another filter? Is that even possible because of the conflicting rules for user role and product tax?

Comment: thank you very much, that does it and I learned a bunch in the process. Have a nice Day and thx again.